# Fabric counter to display how many host are done

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, fabric

I'm trying to create a counter to be able to display "host 5/100 done" at the end of my task. I have a counter classe :

```
class ThreadCounter(object):
   def __init__(self, initval=0):
      self.val =int(initval)
      self.lock = threading.Lock()

  def increment(self):
      with self.lock:
         self.val += 1
  def value(self):
      with self.lock:
         return self.val
```

I tried a few things to make it work : 
In my main function, I call my task giving the counter as argument

```
def main():
  my_counter = ThreadCounter(0)
  execute(the_task,my_counter)
@parallel
def the_task(counter):
  try:
    do---my--stuff
  finally :
    my_counter.increment()
    print my_counter.value()
```

The counter was always at "1" when displayed. I feel like the counter wasn't shared.

I also tried to declare the counter as a `global` but same result.
My last try was giving a `lock` to `the_task` and in `the_task`:

```
with lock :
  counter += 1
  print counter
```

What should I do to share counter between the same fabric tasks ? I'm new with threads in python. (I use python 2.6 (not willingly))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a decorator to track the task completion like,

```
total = 100
count = 0

def counter(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        globals()["count"] += 1
        ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print "host %(count)s/%(total)s done" % globals()
        return ret
    return wrapped

@counter
def first_task(counter):
    # do---my--stuff
    pass

@counter
def second_task(counter):
    # do---my--stuff
    pass
```

Comment: Ow, I forgot to say, my task run in parallel. this do exactly what I wanted, exepted that I think it forces my task to be sequential.